# Standalone Expression Engine site

Tags: wordpress, xampp, expressionengine

I have a client that has a website built in the Expression Engine (this also applies for a WordPress site I have the same requests for).

Basically the client wants an offline version that is distributable say on a cd or usb drive. This also needs to be dummy proof that it's basically a double click and *voila* site is open and offline and functional.

Please let me know of any applications or thoughts you may have on ways to achieve this.
The only thing I have come across is using XAMPP but this then has to be installed on every computer before hand and files to be transferred to the htdocs folder before use - as this is not dummy proof and a bit risky I can't see this as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like:

- export everything as pure HTML, CSS, JavaScript and media assets.
- create the AutoPlay just like any CD-ROM to open the `index.html` file.
- the AutoPlay should have Windows/OSX versions.
- create some JS functions to check for network connection and pull updated content from the live site.

---

Related:

- [How to create an "hybrid" usb stick?](https://superuser.com/questions/129184/how-to-create-an-hybrid-usb-stick)
- [Resources for building public information displays using HTML/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453103/resources-for-building-public-information-displays-using-html-css)